XSLT Grouping issue based on condition
i am trying to write an XSLT which will group all relevant SG9 segment based on SG9 field A_51 where A_50= KAR (xpath: INVR/SG9/SG11/SG14/FFR/C506[A_50='KAR']/A_51 in input xml), after grouping for each group we need to add <TNU>segment in the last, my xslt is not giving exact result, Please check once
Input sample
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<INVR>
    <HNU_S>
        <FIELD1>0002</FIELD1>
    </HNU_S>
    <MGB_S>
        <FIELD1>2410458</FIELD1>
    </MGB_S> 
    <GS2>
        <NODE>
            <FIELD2>SU</FIELD2>           
        </NODE>
    </GS2>
    <SG9>
        <NIL_S>
            <FIELD1>4141</FIELD1>     
        </NIL_S>     
        <SG11>                      
            <SG14>
                <FFR>
                    <C506>
                        <A_50>KAR</A_50>
                        <A_51>1234</A_51>
                    </C506>
                </FFR>
            </SG14>
        </SG11>
    </SG9>
       <SG9>
        <NIL_S>
            <FIELD1>43636</FIELD1>     
        </NIL_S>     
        <SG11>                      
            <SG14>
                <FFR>
                    <C506>
                        <A_50>KAR</A_50>
                        <A_51>4567</A_51>
                    </C506>
                </FFR>
            </SG14>
        </SG11>
    </SG9>
       <SG9>
        <NIL_S>
            <FIELD1>65757</FIELD1>     
        </NIL_S>     
        <SG11>                      
            <SG14>
                <FFR>
                    <C506>
                        <A_50>KKR</A_50>
                        <A_51>1234</A_51>
                    </C506>
                </FFR>
            </SG14>
        </SG11>
    </SG9>
       <SG9>
        <NIL_S>
            <FIELD1>14145</FIELD1>     
        </NIL_S>     
        <SG11>                      
            <SG14>
                <FFR>
                    <C506>
                        <A_50>KKR</A_50>
                        <A_51>4567</A_51>
                    </C506>
                </FFR>
            </SG14>
        </SG11>
    </SG9>
    
    
    <TNU>
        <FIELD1>330</FIELD1>      
    </TNU>
</INVR>

output sample
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<INVR>
    <HNU_S>
        <FIELD1>0002</FIELD1>
    </HNU_S>
    <MGB_S>
        <FIELD1>2410458</FIELD1>
    </MGB_S> 
    <GS2>
        <NODE>
            <FIELD2>SU</FIELD2>           
        </NODE>
    </GS2>
    <group>
    <SG9>
        <NIL_S>
            <FIELD1>4141</FIELD1>     
        </NIL_S>     
        <SG11>                      
            <SG14>
                <FFR>
                    <C506>
                        <A_50>KAR</A_50>
                        <A_51>1234</A_51>
                    </C506>
                </FFR>
            </SG14>
        </SG11>
    </SG9>
     <SG9>
        <NIL_S>
            <FIELD1>65757</FIELD1>     
        </NIL_S>     
        <SG11>                      
            <SG14>
                <FFR>
                    <C506>
                        <A_50>KKR</A_50>
                        <A_51>1234</A_51>
                    </C506>
                </FFR>
            </SG14>
        </SG11>
    </SG9>
    
     <TNU>
        <FIELD1>330</FIELD1>      
    </TNU>
    </group>
    <group>
       <SG9>
        <NIL_S>
            <FIELD1>43636</FIELD1>     
        </NIL_S>     
        <SG11>                      
            <SG14>
                <FFR>
                    <C506>
                        <A_50>KAR</A_50>
                        <A_51>4567</A_51>
                    </C506>
                </FFR>
            </SG14>
        </SG11>
    </SG9>
      
       <SG9>
        <NIL_S>
            <FIELD1>14145</FIELD1>     
        </NIL_S>     
        <SG11>                      
            <SG14>
                <FFR>
                    <C506>
                        <A_50>KKR</A_50>
                        <A_51>4567</A_51>
                    </C506>
                </FFR>
            </SG14>
        </SG11>
    </SG9>
      <TNU>
        <FIELD1>330</FIELD1>      
    </TNU>
    </group>
    
  
</INVR>

XSLT I used
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="
http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="SG9">
        <G_SG9>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::SG9)]"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="SG9" group-by="/INVR/SG9/SG11/SG14/FFR/C506[A_50='KAR']/A_51">
                <group>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                </group>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </G_SG9>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>



Please explain clearly in an edit to your question whether the "output sample" is the one your current code generates or the one you want it to create; if it is the one your current code generates also add the needed/wanted output in the edit of the question.

There are elements with the data <A_50>KKR</A_50> in your XML input sample and in the output they seem to be grouped with those having C506[A_50='KAR'], that doesn't make sense with the description/path you have suggested as the grouping key.

If I understand correctly what you are looking to do, then I think you would create an empty template for SG9 and then have a template matching on TNU that selects and groups the SG9 elements and emits the TNU at the end of each group:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="SG9"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="TNU">
        <xsl:variable name="TNU" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="/INVR/SG9" group-by="SG11/SG14/FFR/C506/A_51">
            <group>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$TNU"/>
            </group>
        </xsl:for-each-group> 
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>

Which produces the following output:
<INVR>
   <HNU_S>
      <FIELD1>0002</FIELD1>
   </HNU_S>
   <MGB_S>
      <FIELD1>2410458</FIELD1>
   </MGB_S>
   <GS2>
      <NODE>
         <FIELD2>SU</FIELD2>
      </NODE>
   </GS2>
   <group>
      <SG9>
         <NIL_S>
            <FIELD1>4141</FIELD1>
         </NIL_S>
         <SG11>
            <SG14>
               <FFR>
                  <C506>
                     <A_50>KAR</A_50>
                     <A_51>1234</A_51>
                  </C506>
               </FFR>
            </SG14>
         </SG11>
      </SG9>
      <SG9>
         <NIL_S>
            <FIELD1>65757</FIELD1>
         </NIL_S>
         <SG11>
            <SG14>
               <FFR>
                  <C506>
                     <A_50>KKR</A_50>
                     <A_51>1234</A_51>
                  </C506>
               </FFR>
            </SG14>
         </SG11>
      </SG9>
      <TNU>
         <FIELD1>330</FIELD1>
      </TNU>
   </group>
   <group>
      <SG9>
         <NIL_S>
            <FIELD1>43636</FIELD1>
         </NIL_S>
         <SG11>
            <SG14>
               <FFR>
                  <C506>
                     <A_50>KAR</A_50>
                     <A_51>4567</A_51>
                  </C506>
               </FFR>
            </SG14>
         </SG11>
      </SG9>
      <SG9>
         <NIL_S>
            <FIELD1>14145</FIELD1>
         </NIL_S>
         <SG11>
            <SG14>
               <FFR>
                  <C506>
                     <A_50>KKR</A_50>
                     <A_51>4567</A_51>
                  </C506>
               </FFR>
            </SG14>
         </SG11>
      </SG9>
      <TNU>
         <FIELD1>330</FIELD1>
      </TNU>
   </group>
</INVR>


I would try along the lines of
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:param name="A_50" as="xs:string*" select="'KAR', 'KKR'"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="INVR">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, * except (SG9, TNU)"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="SG9" group-by="SG11/SG14/FFR/C506[A_50=$A_50]/A_51">
        <group>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group(), ../TNU"/>
        </group>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

assuming you want to group on A_50 with the values KAR and KKR.
